Definitive way to enable ESC-key-like functionality for Obsidian on iPhone
Has anyone provided a good solution to the lack of an escape key on iPhone yet, for vim mode? I feel like this needs a definitive solution, and I’d be willing to work on it if nobody has, yet.
Not an external keyboard. Just a plugin that gives a good way to enter the escape character, like a special button above the keyboard, or a special character sequence that gets remapped to the ESC key code, etc.
What strategy would be the best solution for implementing this, if writing an Obsidian plugin? Like, the most natural way to work within the confines of iOS, and not a kind of awkward workaround.

Would you be willing to paste all of the excellent details as an answer? People will be far more likely to answer or edit your answer to improve it if the question is a paragraph or two and the answer is long to show all the items tried so far and why they might not be ideal.

I found the answer! :inoremap jj  allows a quick sequence jj in insert mode to return you to normal mode!

Can you post a proper answer now, please?
